# HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used

Tags: iis-7.5

i am stuck with a problem. when i hosted my site having two part, UI and Server, when i am trying to login to the system the following error is occurred.  read lot of posts regarding this error and i cannot make it possible. please help me to catch the exact problem

```
                        <div class="logo-container"><h3>DMS<span>Beta</span></h3>
                        </div>


                        <div style="width:55%; float:left;">
                            <h2>Sign In</h2>
                            <div   class="divAlertError"  id="divLoginAlert" style="display:none;">
                                The username or password is incorrect
                            </div>

                            <form method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-signin">

                                <input type="text" id="username" class="input-block-level" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                                <input type="password" id="password" class="input-block-level" name="password" placeholder="Password">

                                <label class="checkbox" style="padding-left:0px;">
                                    Forgot Password
                                </label>
                                    <div class="btn-group">
                                        <button class="btn btn-mini">Action</button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-mini dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                        <span class="caret"></span>
                                        </button>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                         <li>--select--</li>
                                         <li>English -US</li>
                                         <li>English -EN</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn  btn-primary pull-right" id="btnSignIn">Sign in</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p> <center>© EMR 2013.All rights reserved</center></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Login Div ends-->
```

this is the code i am using and the error i that am getting  is

HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.

please help me. i got this error after updating my ui design, before that all pages are working fine..

Regadrs,
Sivajith S.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your form is missing the action attribute.

Comment: if i wrote <form method="POST" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-signin">  there is no change in this error

Comment: Well you need to fill in the url to call as well as making sure the target can handle post.